# Auto height for vertical image-slider between fixed header and footer with pure html/css - is it possible?

Tags: html, css

Sorry, but I couldn't explain it in just in one sentence. So, here's the deal. I build a small website with only html/css. It's main page contains fixed header, fixed footer and main container between them. Main container have five divs. I want height of every div in main container to be exactly equal to the distance between header and footer whether someone open this site on laptop or smartphone. Here is general idea how it looks

```
   <header>
  <ul>
    <li>navbar</li>
    <li>navbar</li>
    <li>navbar</li>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="hero"><p>Picture1</p></div>
  <div class="hero"><p>Picture2</p></div>  
  <div class="hero"><p>Picture3</p></div>  
  <div class="hero"><p>Picture4</p></div>  
  <div class="hero"><p>Picture5</p></div>    
</main>
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li>footer</li>
    <li>footer</li>
    <li>footer</li>
</footer>
```

http://codepen.io/SavageRandy/pen/BQWvyZ

For now I went with a couple of hundreds media queries for different viewport sizes, but it's tedious, unefficient and, I must admit, stupid. For large screens I use vh property, but it doesn't hepl much, because height of viewport and disctance between header and footer change in different speed. 
So, my question is, is it possible with only html/css to setup height of every div in main container exactly equal to the distance between header and footer for different viewports?

P.S. Please, don't get insulted because of my poor English, I take lessons.

Comment: One simple way would be to use `vh` units for the header and footer elements as well as .hero, so all items are proportionate to the screen size. Example: `header, footer { height: 15vh; } .hero { height: 70vh; }` In this example, the header and footer will always be 15% of the screen height (30% total), and the hero elements will each be equal to the remaining 70% of screen height.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that, it will work. But I don't want my footer and header to be too small on smartphones and too big on WQHD and 4K lcds.

Comment: Then you could add a media query that has - for example - a larger mobile version of the header/footer and smaller .hero. Tweak this example to your needs: `@media (max-width: 768px) { header, footer { height: 20vh; } .hero { height: 60vh; } }`

Comment: Sounds interesting. I have to try it on my project to see how it will go. Thank you!

Comment: If your `header` and `footer` are fixed heights, say `40px` each, you could use `height: calc(100vh - 80px)` for the `.hero` class.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know about that, but looks like a very nice idea. Thanks!